# Vscode extension error, java runtime could not be located on window subsystem for linux

Tags: java, linux, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed the java runtime in the window subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu), and the Vscode is installed on the windows 10 system.

I did not install java runtime in windows 10 system. When I use vscode to edit java, it usually pop up a notice says the "java runtime could not be located".

I have point the vscode "java.home" to the java jdk directory of window subsystem linux file folder, which is `C:\\Users\\Myusername\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\\LocalState\\rootfs\\usr\\lib\\jvm\\`. In the folder, it has:

- `java-8-openjdk-amd64` directory, and three files
- `.java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo`,
- `default-java`
- `java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64`.

But however, the vscode still pop out the notice that `the java.home variable defined in VS Code settings does not point to a JDK`.

Can anyone let me know how to set up the vs code properly so that it can locate the JDK file in the window subsystem for Linux (WSL)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It won´t work like this because you are trying to use a jdk builded for linux on windows.
It is the same as if you download the jdk for linux and try to execute on windows.

As for the solution, unfortunately there is no solution right now. 
However you can call your **java** and **javac** directly on terminal using *WSL*

```
wsl javac
```

You can´t point the *java_home* using *wsl*.
Maybe in the future the guys from Microsoft can make the trick. I hope so.